# Marking projects as done when all tasks' progress are 100%

Tags: python, python-2.x, cyclomatic-complexity, odoo

We have `project.task` model, where each task has many lines and each line has progress field indicating how much work has been done and how much still remaining (from 0 to 100 percent). The task cannot be done until all lines' progress is 100%.

```
@api.onchange('task_line_ids','task_line_rider_ids')
def progress_on_change(self):
    for record in self:
        if len(record.task_line_ids) != 0 and record.state in ('open', 'done'):
            all_done = True
            for line in record.task_line_ids or record.task_line_rider_ids:
                if line.progress != 100:
                    all_done = False
                    break         
                if all_done == True:
                    record.state = 'done'
                else:
                    record.state = 'open'
```

However, SonarQube reported a code smell:
[image: SonarQube]

How can the complexity be reduced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in your code. The line:

```
if len(record.task_line_ids) != 0 and record.state in ('open', 'done')
```

Is followed by the line:

```
for line in record.task_line_ids or record.task_line_rider_ids
```

Since `bool(record.task_line_ids)` will always be `True` by the virtue of the list not being empty (as previously checked). This second line is equivalent to

```
for line in record.task_line_ids
```

This does not seem to be the intention of the code. Assuming you want to check all lines in either `record.task_line_ids` and `record.task_line_rider_ids` you may want to use the following code:

```
all_lines = record.task_line_ids + record.task_line_rider_ids
all_done = all(line.progress == 100 for line in all_lines)
```

Combined with the other answer's suggestion, this should result in a pretty clean function.

Answer (score 7):

16 and 15 are pretty artificial values, you should aim for a better code quality rather than a higher/smaller metric in particular.

Let's see what can be improved...

- Your boolean comparison `if all_done == True:` could (and should) be written in a more concise way: `if all_done:`.
- Python has an optional `else` on `for` loops which can be understood as "this loop exited the usual way, not via a break". This removes the need for the `all_done` variable altogether:

  ```
  if len(record.task_line_ids) != 0 and record.state in ('open', 'done'):
      for line in record.task_line_ids or record.task_line_rider_ids:
          if line.progress != 100:
              record.state = 'open'
              break         
      else:
          record.state = 'done'
  ```
- You could use the `all` or `any` builtin to rewrite this without the `for... else` logic:

  ```
  if len(record.task_line_ids) != 0 and record.state in ('open', 'done'):
      if all(line.progress == 100 for line in record.task_line_ids or record.task_line_rider_ids):
          record.state = 'done'
      else:
          record.state = 'open'
  ```
- You could re-introduce the temporary variable and use ternary operator:

  ```
  if len(record.task_line_ids) != 0 and record.state in ('open', 'done'):
      all_done =  all(line.progress == 100 for line in record.task_line_ids or record.task_line_rider_ids)
      record.state = 'done' if all_done else 'open'
  ```